# this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key image view

Tags: ios

Debugger is showing this information:

```
2013-07-16 15:23:15.731 app2[2501:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x71a4140> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key imageview.'
```

My app currently consist of two view controllers.

1. 'ViewController' has just a button to start the app and pressing the button launches the new view.

> ```
> ViewController.h
>
> #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
>
> @interface ViewController : UIViewController
> - (IBAction)startBtn:(id)sender;
>
> @end
> ```

```
ViewController.m

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)startBtn:(id)sender {

    UIViewController *flipViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AppViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    [self presentViewController:flipViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];

}

@end
```

My second view controller 'AppViewController' has a UIImageView and a UIButton. It's code is:

```
AppViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview;

@end
```

and

```
AppViewController.m

#import "AppViewController.h"

@interface AppViewController ()

@end

@implementation AppViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

The problem I am facing is that the moment I connect the property between the 'xib' file and 'h' file by Ctrl-dragging the image view into the 'h' file, my app crashes in the simulator and gives me the error.

I reckon this might be too simple of an error for many of you, however, I am unable to rectify it. I have read numerous posts on this forum and have tried most, including the @synthesize fix and the like.

Comment: Just for future debugging, whenever I get that particular error, I turn on the breakpoint for All Exceptions. Then debugger usually (most of the time) stops where it's useful. Here's a tutorial on how to do this: http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `flipViewController` should be a `AppViewController`.

The issue is that `AppViewController` is a subclass of `UIViewController` so you are allowed to instantiate it as a `UIViewController`, but you lose access to all the additional properties that your `AppViewController` adds on top of `UIViewController`'s.

Your button handler should look like:

```
- (IBAction)startBtn:(id)sender {

    AppViewController *flipViewController = [[AppViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AppViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    [self presentViewController:flipViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Comment: Above code gives me the error "Use of undeclared identifier 'AppViewController'." BTW, this method is in ViewController, not in AppViewController.

Comment: You'll have to add an `#import "AppViewController.h"` to the top of your ViewController.h (or ViewController.m, it really doesn't matter which).